# can't boot into arch linux after fresh installation

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, system-installation, boot-loader

So I just tried to install archlinux a bunch of time without being able to boot to it, I searched my problem and found a lot of people having the same problem and I tried a bunch of things but unfortunately I didn't succeed. Asking about my problem here is my last resort so I hope somebody can help me and I hope I learn a thing or two after solving my problem.
(sorry for my bad english).
So I'll start with sharing the steps I did to install archLinux:

1. Boot up the live system with usb drive
2. Verify that I'm booted in EFI mode with this command `ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars` (this gives me a bunch of gibberish which means I'm in efi mode as said in arch's official installation guide)
3. Partitioning the disk with `fdisk /dev/nvme0n1`:

   - Create a GPT partition table with option `g`
   - 512M: EFI partition----->(/dev/nvme0n1p1)
   - 4G: swap partition------>(/dev/nvme0n1p2)
   - rest: root partition------->(/dev/nvme0n1p3)
   - writing changes to disk
4. formatting created partitions with the following commands:

   - `mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/nvme0n1p1`
   - `mkswap /dev/nvme0n1p2`
   - `mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p3`
5. Mount the partitions:

   - `mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt`
   - `swapon /dev/nvme0n1p2`
6. Install essential packages on `/mnt`: `pacstrap /mnt base linux linux-firmware`
7. Generate `fstab` file:  `genfstab -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab`
8. Chroot into /mnt:  `arch-chroot /mnt`
9. Generate `initramfs`: `mkinitcpio -P`
10. Installing grub and some other packages: `pacman -S grub efibootmgr os-prober base-devel mtools dosfstools...`
11. Create `EFI` boot directory and mount it: `mkdir /boot/EFI && mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/EFI`
12. Install `Grub bootloader`: `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --bootloader-id=grub_uefi --recheck`
13. Generate `Grub Config`: `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
14. `Exit` chroot, Unmount partitions `umount -a`, `reboot`

! All commands were prompted successfully without an error

Note: some steps are skipped like setting timezone, hostname, hosts, adding user etc.

after reboot arch doesn't boot up and the uefi menu has only `enter setup` which will get me to the bios.

Am I missing something here??? or am I doing something wrongggg??? Help Please!!!

andddd
thanks in advanceee <3

*EDIT:*

I reinstalled grub bootloader and regenerated the grub Configuration with the same commands in steps 12 and 13

**before rebooting my computer**
the output of `efibootmgr -v` is

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001
Boot0000* grub_uefi HD(1,GPT,d20bff6e-6f1e-c549-9f1b-505a302fd42c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\grub_uefi\grubx64.efi)
Boot0001* UEFI: Generic Flash Disk 8.07, Partition 1 ...Gibberish..BO
```

**but After reboot the output is:**

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001
Boot0001* UEFI: Generic Flash Disk 8.07, Partition 1 ...Gibberish..BO
```

Comment: Can you see the EFI entry for "Arch" in your BIOS settings? (From the live USB) what does `efibootmgr` show?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `efibootmgr -v` after running `modprobe efivars`. Maybe check if Arch has an entry in your BIOS.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I already mentioned that the only output in the EFI entry is `Enter Setup` which will get me into the bios if I click it.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks for your feedback. 
question edited.

Comment: I can think of two things: 1. secure boot not disabled 2. your uefi firmware is broken: try adding `--removable` when `grub-install`

Comment: Ohhhh you saved my life @TomYan thankksss <3
secure boot was disabled so I tried --removable and it workeddddd

Comment: @TomYan - You should post that as an answer

Comment: @Greenonline how to do that? his answer is in the comments section

Comment: @AzerSD If TomYan found the answer, it's only appropriate that they get the credit for it. Since a comment isn't an Answer, it's also fair for someone else to post the answer. I see that you (the OP) have done so now, circa 8 hours after Tom's answer.  Another option that I've used in these situations is a community-wiki answer, if you feel like declining any reputation points gained from posting Tom's comment as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just forget `efi_directory` folder to grub configuration file

try this:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub
```

You don't need to reinstall you system just re-mount the system and run `arch-chroot /mnt` and generate grub configuration again. Remember to also run

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Another thing on **step 11**:

> Create EFI boot directory and mount it: mkdir /boot/EFI && mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/EFI

You have to do this part before generate `fstab` so you system needs to boot properly...

Give us some feedback if it helped. `grub` has changed some configuration directly on kernel and don't use `os-prober` by default anymore (if you are trying to run a dual boot system)

Comment: unfortentaly that didn't change anything.
and no I'm not trying to run a dual boot system
I had windows 11 but now I'm totally switching to arch.
I edited my question you can check it again.

thanks for your try <3

Comment: The ESP was NOT used for `/boot` in his setup / procedures btw.

Comment: What about `fstab`? @TomYan I've done with ESP and worked fine, I think `grub` changed to work without ESP, but you can use btw